# How to get attributes of extensions

Tags: jquery, yii, yii-extensions

I want to `fetch extension attributes` value in any extension of `yii.`

Ex Below:

```
$this->widget('xupload.XUpload', array(
            'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("site/upload", array("parent_id" => 1)),
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'file',
            'multiple' => true,
            'options' => array('submit' => 'js:function (){

            }')
        ));
```

i want to fetch suppose URL of above extension in submit function of options but how to?

Comment: So, for example, you wanted something like `${url}` to put into your `js:function...` string? And to make it into actual url value by Yii?

Comment: @PeterM- not getting properly.. error generate...can u give me proper syntax for getting value.

Comment: You should create a js var with the needed value, or get the value from the widget generated html code (show us).

Comment: @harsh4u It's not syntax, I just used this to clarify question, syntax showed in my comment will not work.

Answer (score 2):

It will not be possible to access the url, or any other attribute of an extension, ***when the extension is being initialized***. But we can access the attribute **after** the widget has been initialized.

When you call `$this->widget('extension', array( ... ));` the [widget is being initialized](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#widget-detail), so the options passed in the array can't be immediately used within another option. In your case you are trying to access the property `url` within the property `options`.

To use the property we have to:

1. Store a reference to the widget after it has been initialized, like:

   ```
   $xwidget = $this->widget('extension', array( ... ));
   ```
2. Then use/access a property :

   ```
   $xwidget->propertyname;
   ```

For your exact scenario when you want to pass the property to a js function, you will **additionally** have to do the following:

1. Instead of passing an anonymous function to the `submit` option, pass a function reference:

   ```
   'options' => array('submit' => 'submitHandler')
   ```
2. Then either register a script with `registerScript` or use direct html `<script>` tag, and access the widget's property in it:

   ```
   Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('script-id','
       function submitHandler() {
           var url = "'. $xwidget->url .'"; // this is how we can insert the property into js
           // ... more code ...
       }',
       CClientScript::POS_END// the position of the script
   );
   ```

Comment: Harsh4u, I have made a few edits to better explain the solution, be sure to check it out.